# D3 circle like network diagram with central node and links between all nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I al trying to build a network diagram where the main node is in the center of a circle like network and all the other nodes are at the circumference. All the nodes have connections to each other depending on how they are connected. The central node is connected to all the nodes. where the other nodes are randomly connected.

I have tried to do it but I can not get this to work. I am sorry if I do not have an example as I am very new to D3.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like a spring graph (e.g. getspringy.com)?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Sorry if the question was confusing. I am looking for an example of D3 network diagram with a circle like layout. The center node is at the center of the circle and all the other nodes are at the circumference. The nodes are all connected to the center one, and they have also connections to each other.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a d3 force layout, or perhaps the [cola layout](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/).

Comment: I tried force layout but I am really trying to get an example working and I can not get it to work. Thanks